# scaling lines weight in folium (polyline or antpath)

Tags: python, leaflet, width, line, folium

I draw lines and ant path in folium and I need to scale width of line for example 12 km width line but I can't use simple weight because it has dynamic width that changed when zoom in or out

```
loc = [[64.18563, 66.846756],
       [-64.38807, 26.490042]]

# draw moving line between 2 points
plugins.AntPath(loc,
                color='red',
                weight=12("12 km"),
                opacity=0.5).add_to(m)
```

poly lines way

```
 loc = [[64.18563, 66.846756],
       [-64.38807, 26.490042]]

# draw moving line between 2 points
plugins.polylines(loc,
                color='red',
                weight=50("50 km"),
                opacity=0.5).add_to(m)
```

[image]

[image]

**As you see in pictures with every zoom in or out change width of line,Is there any way to chnage this(scale line width or stabilize width )?**